# Cloning Resource Group on Azure error: The account XYZ is already in another resource group in this susbscription

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

I need to clone a `Resource Group` on Azure. To test the process I created a new one, and added one `VM` to it.

Then I went to `Resource Groups > [my group] > Automation Script > Deploy`, accepted the terms and conditions and clicked `Purchase`.

The result is this error:

```
{"telemetryId":"05cbc6fb-2597...", "bladeInstanceId":"Blade_f46316807e514f23acb93...","galleryItemId":"Microsoft.Template","createBlade":"DeployToAzure","code":"InvalidTemplateDeployment","message":"The template deployment 'Microsoft.Template' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '4f29d0ac-30b8...'. See inner errors for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.","details":[{"code":"PreflightValidationCheckFailed","message":"Preflight validation failed. Please refer to the details for the specific errors.","details":[{"code":"StorageAccountInAnotherResourceGroup","target":"appsvcr...","message":"The account appsvc... is already in another resource group in this susbscription."}]}]}
```

The error description is

```
The account appsvc... is already in another resource group in this susbscription
```

I tried editing the template, or the parameters, to remove the `Storage Account`, or move the `storage account` itself, but then I get an error that the account cannot be empty.

Any idea how to solve this?

EDIT: the `parameters` tab from the `Deploy` section:

`{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "virtualMachines_TestRGVM1_name": {
            "value": null
        },
        "networkInterfaces_testrgvm114_name": {
            "value": null
        },
        "networkInterfaces_testrgvm1440_name": {
            "value": null
        },
        "publicIPAddresses_TestRGVM1_ip_name": {
            "value": null
        },
        "publicIPAddresses_TestRGVM1ip746_name": {
            "value": null
        },
        "networkSecurityGroups_TestRGVM1_nsg_name": {
            "value": null
        },
        "networkSecurityGroups_TestRGVM1nsg740_name": {
            "value": null
        },
        "storageAccounts_appsvcrglinuxcentralu225_name": {
            "value": null
        },
        "virtualNetworks_appsvc_rg_Linux_CentralUS_vnet_name": {
            "value": null
        },
        "virtualNetworks_TestCloningBase_virtual_network_name": {
            "value": null
        },
        "securityRules_SSH_name": {
            "value": null
        },
        "securityRules_RDP_name": {
            "value": null
        },
        "securityRules_SSH_name_1": {
            "value": null
        },
        "securityRules_RDP_name_1": {
            "value": null
        },
        "disks_TestRGVM1_OsDisk_1_fa82f490edc742d4b4fc47cf9d8f1a77_name": {
            "value": null
        },
        "subnets_default_name": {
            "value": null
        },
        "subnets_default_name_1": {
            "value": null
        },
        "securityRules_Ports_22000_22005_name": {
            "value": null
        },
        "virtualMachines_TestRGVM1_id": {
            "value": null
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change storage account name to something else as storage account names have to be unique across all Azure. depending on how your template is structured you would need to modify parameters\variables\hardcoded values

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and got this error: `Deployment to resource group 'TestCloneRG2' failed.
Additional details from the underlying API that might be helpful: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.`

Comment: as you might have noticed this doesnt specify what is going wrong, so there is no way to identify the problem. i suggest you accept this answer and start a new question where you paste your template

Comment: The template is 15,000 over the character the StackOverflow limit. Would copying parts of it help?

Comment: you can use gists or pastebin or whatever, but if you are using 15k lines template chances are no one is going to help you (especially if its autogenerated, as they are garbage)

Comment: I edited the question to add the `Parameters` tab from the `Deploy` section. It's reasonably short. Could it be that the issue is with the resource group being in one location, and the storage in another? (a wild guess)

Comment: no, thats not how it works, doesnt matter what region storage account is, its name have to be unique across all of the azure clients (not just you). i dont see this error in the [common errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors). storage account has to be in the same region if you are doing something with VM and storage account, but the error would be different

Comment: Try the activity log in the portal, failing that - if you can supply a trackingId we can have a look.